# What happens if terminal is resized in ncurses `doupdate`?

Tags: ncurses

The `doupdate` function in ncurses will try to update screen size if necessary:

`ncurses/tty/tty_update.c`:

```
if ((SP_PARM->_endwin == ewSuspend)
|| _nc_handle_sigwinch(SP_PARM)) {
/*
 * This is a transparent extension:  XSI does not address it,
 * and applications need not know that ncurses can do it.
 *
 * Check if the terminal size has changed while curses was off
 * (this can happen in an xterm, for example), and resize the
 * ncurses data structures accordingly.
 */
_nc_update_screensize(SP_PARM);
}
```

My question is:

What happens if the terminal is resized **after** this check is done, but **before** anything is actually written to the terminal? If the function writes to the terminal in its new size but believes in its old size, will it crash the program or cause other undefined behavior?

It seems `_nc_flush` merely flushes displayed texts and terminal control characters to the output file descriptor. But I still have no idea what is the worst thing that can happen if there is a sizing problem. Is it always recoverable, meaning there is no crash and everything will work again once the library finds the correct terminal size?

Comment: The worst (and most likely) thing that can happen is that the display will be messed up. Most character cell programs have a keyboard shortcut for redrawing the screen, usually Ctrl-L. *Stuff* can always mess up a terminal display, so it is polite to give the user a way to request a complete repainting.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with the comment: not much will happen if the terminal is resized before ncurses can obtain a new/improved size.  Some characters may be written to the "wrong" location, but since ncurses cannot determine what is actually ***on*** the terminal's screen, it cannot misuse that information to (for example) write beyond the limits of an array which records what is on the screen.

The issue with handling `SIGWINCH` is to ensure that ncurses does the ***["unsafe"](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)*** operations outside the signal handler.  The signal handler only sets a variable which ncurses can inspect (safely).

Applications can detect the `SIGWINCH` when `wgetch` returns `KEY_RESIZE`.  As a side-effect of returning `KEY_RESIZE` (see *[NOTES](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h2-NOTES)* in manual page), ncurses will clear the physical screen via an *[internal call](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/a1103108be6ef58d087f33755efd11939da42109/ncurses/base/resizeterm.c#L497)* to [`clearok`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html#h3-clearok) (reducing the need for a user to press some special key to force a refresh):

> If **`clearok`** is called with **`TRUE`** as argument, the next call  to  **`wrefresh`**
> with this window will clear the screen completely and redraw the entire
> screen from scratch.  This is useful when the contents  of  the  screen
> are  *uncertain*, or in some cases for a more pleasing visual effect.  If
> the *`win`* argument to **`clearok`** is the global  variable  **`curscr`**,  the  next
> call  to  **`wrefresh`**  with any window causes the screen to be cleared and
> repainted from scratch.

In practice, that works well enough (for programs which are designed to use `KEY_RESIZE` to remind them to repaint things that ncurses cannot do).  The [`dialog`](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) program does this, for example (see [source-code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/7949bc77b9e3037b99ca2c0ec53db5df9a7afd60/buildlist.c#L1098))

An application developer may still want to have a repaint-key to handle system messages, e.g., using [`wall`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/shutdown.8.html) (which can clutter up the screen).